# Multiply by -1 VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have the below code which has an error 1004 within. Please can someone suggest why this is happening? The aim of this code is to multiply the desired range by -1.

```
   Range("A2").Value = -1
   Dim Lrow As Long
   Lrow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RING").Columns(1).Find("%,FPROJECT_ID,TPROJECTS,NPORTFOLIO,NNON_PORTFOLIO").Row
   Range("A2").Copy
   Range("BJ:CI" & Lrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlMultiply, _
   SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually need to specifiy the row for the full range. So it must be

```
Range("BJ" & Lrow & ":CI" & Lrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll,        Operation:=xlMultiply, _
 SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

so Excel knows where to paste to.

Comment: Thanks! I definitely should have realised that one!